# Drag and Shoot in unity2d with moving camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, drag

I have been facing an issue in using a Drag and Shoot launcher. I am taking the mouse position as input and converting it to world coordinates. Those world coordinates are also being used to draw a line renderer "lr" as Drag line to show aim direction and power. The problem I have is when the camera is moving. When the camera is moving, the startpoint goes out of view and dragpoint keeps on changing with camera even if the mouse position is still. I want the startpoint and dragpoint to not get affected by the camera movement and should only be the coordinates at which we have the mouse clicked and holded.

I tried
startPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - Camera.main.transform.position;

This solves the problem but the line renderer stops showing the line of drag.

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            lr.positionCount = 1;
            lr.SetPosition(0, startPoint);

            Debug.Log(startPoint);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            dragPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            lr.positionCount = 2;
            lr.SetPosition(1, dragPoint);
            
            Debug.Log(dragPoint);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            lr.positionCount = 0;
            endPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            //endPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - Camera.main.transform.position;

            force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - endPoint.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - endPoint.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
            rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            //SoundManager.instance.PlaySfx(release);
            groundCheck = false;
            groundCheck2 = false;
        }
```

Here is a video for the issue:
https://clipchamp.com/watch/RT28iA9Lgei

Comment: `I want the startpoint and dragpoint to not get affected by the camera movement and should only be the coordinates at which we have the mouse clicked and holded.` .. this sounds achievable for the `startpoint` ... but how is the `dragpoint` supposed to stay the same if the camera is moving?

Comment: You could of course simply store the previous `Input.mousePosition` and only process the drag if it was changed if that is what you mean ... still it would jump of course according o the current camera position / perspective

Comment: how can I store the start point in world coordinates and add the relevant camera movement to it so the startpoint remains at a constant position on the screen.

Comment: well as to my understanding you can't ... either you store a consistent **world space** position => if your camera moves .. well it won't match your original touch/mouse point anymore since the camera now displays a different part of your world ... or you store your point in **screen space** => regardless of what the underlying world position is it is a fixed point on your screen ... that's your two options .. I don't really understand what your actual goal is with that

Comment: I used screen space for the points but cannot figure out the line renderer using Pixel coordinates. Can I use line renderer with screen space coordinates and if so then how. Here a video of the problem https://vimeo.com/757847608.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ah I think I get it now, thanks for the video that really helps! So you basically want to **only** use the static screen (=pixel) space coordinates. However, the `LineRenderer` would be the issue here as it requires world space points. One alternative might be to not use a `LineRenderer` at all but rather a simple image you just scale and rotate accordingly. Otherwise yes I guess you would need to store and calculate in screen space positions and rather each and every frame update the line renderer world space positions

Answer (score 1):

As said the simplest solution I can imagine would be to store the positions always in persistent **screen space**.

And then only convert to world space in order to apply them to the line

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    startPoint = Input.mousePosition;
    lr.positionCount = 1;
    lr.SetPosition(0, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(startPoint));
}

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    dragPoint = Input.mousePosition;
    lr.positionCount = 2;
    lr.SetPosition(0, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(startPoint);
    lr.SetPosition(1, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(dragPoint));
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    lr.positionCount = 0;
    endPoint = Input.mousePosition;

    var delta = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(startPoint) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(endPoint);

    force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(delta.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(delta.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
    rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    //SoundManager.instance.PlaySfx(release);
    groundCheck = false;
    groundCheck2 = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This has almost fixed the problem. The only issue now is that the line renderer is working and visible in SCENE View but not in the GAME view.... The startpoint, dragpoint and endpoint are Vector2 in the script. Here's a video : https://vimeo.com/759764069

Comment: Funny that you were the only person who attempted to help in my only Unity based post, and ultimately I wound up going a different route, but I ran into this exact issue that the poster is having and your solution/explanation fixed it. Thanks haha!